# DbContext.SaveChanges() always assigns value of id column to zero

Tags: c#, dbcontext

I'm trying to develop a simple application in c# with fluent api. I want to insert a record my Musteri table (Musteri means Customer in Turkish).

My musteri class is in ModelRepository.cs :

```
public class Musteri // It means Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int MusteriId  { get; set; }// It Means CustomerId
    public string MusteriAdi { get; set; } // It means CustomerName
}
```

The following codes are under form1.cs :

```
public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomerContext()
        : base("MySqlConnString") // I'm using MySql Database
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Musteri> MusteriTb { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I'm using following codes to insert record my Musteri (Customer) table

```
CustomerContext context = new CustomerContext();
Musteri MusteriRow = new Musteri();
MusteriRow.MusteriId = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
MusteriRow.MusteriAdi = TexBox2.Text;
context.MusteriTb.Add(MusteriRow);
```

For example I'm writing "9" into TextBox1. I'm watching with breakpoint MusteriRow.MusteriId value. Until here MusteriRow.MusteriId = 9.

After `context.SaveChanges()` command MusteriRow.MusteriId is being 0 (zero). Always program assigns value of MusteriRow.MusteriId to Zero. How can i solve this problem. Please help me.

Comment: can you show the code where the object is added to the context, and then context.SaveChanges() is called? Is the string value being saved correctly?

Comment: Do you have any Maps of the entities? Do you want the id to be 9? What value is it in the database? Is `MusteriId` auto incremented?

Comment: The id is most likely set to the generated id from the database. It's weird that you get a 0 every time though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I changed my model class like that :

```
public class Musteri
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int MusteriId { get; set; }
    public string MusteriAdi { get; set; }
}
```

I found answer from this link :
[Getting "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" when trying to save with .Add() method using DbContext . Please check my POCO's and save method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739222/getting-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-when-trying-to-save-with-add)

Comment: Some of us aren't allowed to do this because every database change will overwrite our code when we reverse engineer the code from the db.